# PHP - enviar datos de un formulario a un modal bootstrap con php oop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap

espero puedan ayudarme.
no muestra ningún error y que no responde al hacer clic en el botón Guardar. He probado el código de inserción PHP en otra página sin arranque y funciona Me pregunto por qué no está funcionando en modal dialog.

anexo codigo para ver si alguien puede ayudarme a solucionarlo.

este en el archivo "category.php" donde cargo la lista y tengo el formulario modal de bootstrap.

```
    <?php
       $user = new User($db); //Objecto

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $link = $_POST['link'];

            if($user->create($name,$link)) //INSERTAR
            {
                header("Location: category.php?inserted");
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: category.php?failure");
            }
        }

        if(isset($_GET['inserted']))
        {
            echo "Exito";
        }
        else if(isset($_GET['failure']))
        {
            echo "Error";
        }

        echo "<div class='page-wrapper'>";

            echo "<div class='page-content'>";

                echo "<div class='container-fluid-md'>";
                    echo "<div class='row'>";

                            echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myAdd'>Añadir</button>";

                        ?>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                echo "<form id='formADD' method='POST' action='#'>";
                echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                                echo "<label for='nm'>Nombre</label>";
                                echo "<input type='text' id="name" class='form-control' id='nm' name='name'>";
                            echo "</div>";

                            echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                                echo "<label for='nm'>Url</label>";
                                echo "<input type='text' id="url" class='form-control' id='nm' name='link'>";
                            echo "</div>";


                            echo "</form>";
                ?>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                <button type="button" id="button"class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Añadir</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

                        <?php

                    echo "</div>";

                echo "</div>";

            echo "</div>";

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#button").click(function(){

            var pathname = window.location.pathname;
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var url = $("#url").val();
            var parentID = $("#parent").val();
            // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
            var data = 'name1='+ name + '&url1='+ url;

            if(name=='' || url==''|| parentID=='')
            {
                alert("Please Fill All Fields");
            }
            else
            {
                // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'nav-menus.php',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert(result);
                },
                 error: function(result) {
                    alert("Local error callback.", result);
                  }
                });
            }
            return false;
            });
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: por qué usas php para llenar el `.modal-body`? es puro html

Comment: porque quiero usar php para ingresar en modal dialog bootstrap, creo que esta mal

Comment: 1. Porque no usas ajax para controlar de forma más detallada la respuesta? 2. Que te muestra la consola?

Comment: @JuanFernandoz no tengo ajax pero no necesita url directo al archivo PHP.

Comment: @DiegoSagredo Parece como si tu problema estuviera asociado a la inserción de los elementos en el DOM. 

Te recomendaria controlar todo mediante eventos una vez se cargue la totalidad del DOM. Por ejemplo, con la función Ready de jquery.

Comment: @JuanFernandoz pero un parametro "form" , ejemplo $(docuemnt).ready(function(){
 $("form").click(function(){
alert("Prueba");
});
}); y pero como envia un valor $_POST['submit']

Comment: @JuanFernandoz y agrego jquery con ajax pero no se url.

Answer (score 1):

en primer lugar tienes que cuidar que estas asignando 2 veces el `id` a los `<input>` que estas agregando y es importante que si en el echo estas utilizando comillas dobles, utilices comillas simples para el contenido del echo.

Una vez verificado esto, tienes que modificar tus 2 `<input>`  a algo como lo siguiente:

```
echo "<input type='text' id='name' class='form-control' name='name'>";

echo "<input type='text' id='url' class='form-control' name='link'>";
```

En cuanto a el envió de tu formulario por medio de AJAX, tienes que asignar el valor de url como el de tu archivo actual que en este caso es `category.php` , ademas tienes que enviar los parámetros con el nombre que los piensas recibir en tu `PHP` que en este caso los nombres son `name` y `link` por lo que tu codigo de AJAX debería quedar algo como lo siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'category.php',
   data: { name: name, link: url },
   cache: false,
   success: function(result) {
          alert(result);
   },
   error: function(result) {
          alert("Local error callback.", result);
   }
});
```